# How can I let multiple Azure users log into their accounts on one Windows 10 machine?

Tags: azure, windows-10, office365

We currently utilize Microsoft 365 for nonprofits. I have set up users/mailboxes for each of our staff members. We have a machine which is sporadically shared by the entire office running Windows 10. Instead of creating multiple local accounts, is it possible to have the Windows 10 login prompt accept their AD username and password for their own desktop experience? Is this simply Virtual Desktop territory?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please note that Stack Overflow is focussed on Programming. Your question doesn't seem to be about that. However, Stack Overflow has many sister sites. Your question seems more suited for [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com). Also note that it's worthwhile to check out the respective help pages [Stack Overflow's On Topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) or [Server Fault's On Topic](https://serverfault.com/help/on-topic) before posting a question.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understand you correctly but I give a try. 
If you want to log with AD credential you need to add Vm to your domain. After that, add AD account to Remote Desktop Users on the vm. 
By default you can connect with one session to Win10.